# Stockfish (v15.1) problem with creating a shared library (.so) in Android Studio

Tags: stockfish

I'm using **Windows** and **Anroid Studio** with **CMakeList.txt**. I'm getting the following errors during the build process. The libstockfish.a file is generated but there is no .so file I need. Who can help with my problem?

```
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\WB\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\25.1.8937393\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe --target=aarch64-none-linux-android29 --sysroot=C:/Users/WB/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -std=c++17 -fno-limit-debug-info  -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,--no-rosegment -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -shared -Wl,-soname,libstockfish.so -o C:\Users\WB\AndroidStudioProjects\08.05\Stockfish2\app\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\6b651r66\obj\arm64-v8a\libstockfish.so CMakeFiles/stockfish.dir/benchmark.cpp.o CMakeFiles/stockfish.dir/bitbase.cpp.o CMakeFiles/stockfish.dir/bitboard.cpp.o CMakeFiles/stockfish.dir/endgame.cpp.o CMakeFiles/stockfish.dir/evaluate.cpp.o CMakeFiles/stockfish.dir/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/stockfish.dir/material.cpp.o CMakeFiles/stockfish.dir/misc.cpp.o CMakeFiles/stockfish.dir/movegen.cpp.o CMakeFiles/stockfish.dir/movepick.cpp.o CMakeFiles/stockfish.dir/pawns.cpp.o CMakeFiles/stockfish.dir/position.cpp.o CMakeFiles/stockfish.dir/psqt.cpp.o CMakeFiles/stockfish.dir/search.cpp.o CMakeFiles/stockfish.dir/thread.cpp.o CMakeFiles/stockfish.dir/timeman.cpp.o CMakeFiles/stockfish.dir/tt.cpp.o CMakeFiles/stockfish.dir/tune.cpp.o CMakeFiles/stockfish.dir/uci.cpp.o CMakeFiles/stockfish.dir/ucioption.cpp.o  C:/Users/WB/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/29/liblog.so  -latomic -lm && cd ."

ld: error: undefined symbol: Stockfish::Eval::NNUE::load_eval(std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> >, std::__ndk1::basic_istream<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char> >&)
>>> referenced by evaluate.cpp:98 (C:/Users/WB/AndroidStudioProjects/08.05/Stockfish2/app/src/main/cpp/evaluate.cpp:98)
>>>               CMakeFiles/stockfish.dir/evaluate.cpp.o:(Stockfish::Eval::NNUE::init())
>>> referenced by evaluate.cpp:114 (C:/Users/WB/AndroidStudioProjects/08.05/Stockfish2/app/src/main/cpp/evaluate.cpp:114)
>>>               CMakeFiles/stockfish.dir/evaluate.cpp.o:(Stockfish::Eval::NNUE::init())
```

I'm using the Develocode 777 instructions from the site:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43566840/how-does-one-integrate-stockfish-into-an-android-app](https://stackoverflow.com)